# Passing a value from NSObject class back to UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, methods, uiviewcontroller

I don't know why this is being so difficult but I can't get this to work. Here's my basic flow:

I have a UIViewController with a subview UIView which itself has a subview UIButton. Clicking the button instantiates a new instance of a NSObject called TwitterController, creates a NSURL for the twitter feed and then hands control over to TC to do the URLConnection and serialize the data returned.

Here's the relevant code in ViewController (Pruit_Igoe is me, feel free to follow though I don't post much : D) :

```
- (void) getTwitter {

//load new manager
twitterManager = [TwitterController new];
[twitterManager showTwitterFeed:vTwitterFeed:self];

NSURL* twitterFeedPath = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=Pruit_Igoe"];

[twitterManager getTwitterFeed:twitterFeedPath];

//toggle the twitter view
[self toggleView:vTwitterFeed];
[self toggleView:vContactCard];

}
```

- showTwitterFeed dumps the objects in the view vTwitterFeed (button to close the view, images,  etc.)
- getTwitterFeed begins the NSURLConnection process

in TwitterController, I get the twitter feed and process it here:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection  {

//do something with the data!
NSError *e = nil;
//parse the json data
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: receivedData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

//dump it into an array
tweetArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(NSDictionary* thisTweetDict in jsonArray) { 

    NSString* tweet = [thisTweetDict objectForKey:@"text"];
    [tweetArray addObject:tweet];
}

}
```

this all works fine, log tweetArray and all the text is there, log thisTweetDict and all the ton of data Twitter sends back is there. The problem is I want to pass tweetArray back to ViewController but I can't seem to figure out how to.

I've done the following:

Tried returning TweetArray from getTwitterFeed but it came back as null (my guess is the method returned the array before the connection had finished)

Tried to put it in UserDefaults but I keep getting null (same guess as above, but then I put it in connectionDidFinish and still null)

Tried to pass a reference to ViewController to TwitterController and then call a method in VC to pass the array to but in TwitterController I error out because it says my instance of VC doesn't recognize the selector. (It's there, I've triple checked).

I am sure this is simple and I am just being dense but could someone help me with this?

Edit: Here's how I tried to pass it back to VC:

I would pass VC to TC using this method (this is in VC)

```
[twitterManager showTwitterFeed:vTwitterFeed:self];
```

in VC.h I had a UIViewController* thisViewController

in VC.m in the showTwitterFeed:

```
- (void) showTwitterFeed : (UIView* ) theTwitterView :  (UIViewController* ) theViewController {

    thisViewController = theViewController;

    //...other code to build view objects
```

then in

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection { 

...

for(NSDictionary* thisTweetDict in jsonArray) { 

    NSString* tweet = [thisTweetDict objectForKey:@"text"];
    [tweetArray addObject:tweet];
}

[thisViewController getTwitterFeed:tweetArray]; //<--this would error out saying selector not available
```

back in VC.h

```
- (void) getTwitterFeed : (NSArray* ) theTwitterFeed;
```

and in VC.m

```
- (void) getTwitterFeed : (NSArray* ) theTwitterFeed { 

    NSLog(@"%@", theTwitterFeed);
}
```

Comment: can you post the code where you tried to put tweetArray in the view controller ? and its definition ?

Comment: Yep, hold on for a few seconds and I'll have it in...

Answer (score 0):

You can't return it from `getTwitterFeed` because `connectionDidFinishLoading` has not been called yet.

What you need to do is set up a protocol in your `TwitterController` and make your `ViewController` the `delegate` of the `TwitterController`.

Then when `connectionDidFinishLoading` occurs and you save the twitter information you can call the function back to your `delegate` (the `ViewController`).

Create a function called something like `twitterDataReceived:(NSDictionary *)tweetDict` in the `TwitterController` protocol and call it in the `connectionDidFinishLoading` function: `[self.delegate twitterDataReceived:thisTweetDict];`  or if you just want to send the text make it `twitterTextReceived:(NSString *)theTweet` and call `[self.delegate twitterTextReceived:tweet];` or use an array like `twitterArrayReceived:(NSArray *)tweetArray` and `[self.delegate twitterArrayReceived:tweetArray];`, or whatever you want to send back.

If you are unfamiliar with setting up a protocol and a delegate there are many questions available which will help you out, like this one:[objective-c protocol delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314099/protocol-delegate-question)

Answer (score 0):

You get an unrecognized selector because `thisViewController` is of type `UIViewController` which does not have this method defined (Although its not seen from the code you posted I am absolutely sure this is the case as you would get a compilation error when assigning  `thisViewController = theViewController` and `theViewController` type is `UIViewController`)

So change `thisViewController` type to your customized view controller and also change the signature of

`(void) showTwitterFeed : (UIView* ) theTwitterView :  (UIViewController* ) theViewController`

to be :

`(void) showTwitterFeed : (UIView* ) theTwitterView :  (<Your custom controller type>* ) theViewController`